# Problemas com GROUP BY + JOIN no SQL

Tags: sql

Eu tenho duas tabelas, uma pets e outra pessoas, relação de um pra muitas (pessoas podem ter vários pets) e to tentando selecionar os pets agrupando-os por pessoa, mas a minha query no SQL retorna não retorna agrupado https://prnt.sc/SDniXdX54QtZ. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não publique imagens , publique na forma de texto. Publique a estrutura das tabelas. O que seria "não retorna agrupado" , seria o caso da pessoa com mais de um pet ou sem pets ?

Answer (score -1):

O problema da sua consulta é que voce está adicionando no agrupamento o campo `b.id`. Quando você utiliza a agregação no SQL, sua consulta sempre vai sempre agrupar as tuplas pelo elemento com menor granularidade, que no caso é o id da tabela `Pets`.

Se você quiser saber a quantidade de Pets associados a uma Pessoa, recomendo você remover o parâmetro `b.Id` do GROUP BY e adicionar o `COUNT(*)` nos elementos retornados no seu SELECT, que a sua consulta vai passar a retornar as Pessoas da sua tabela e a contagem de Pets agrupados a ela.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, COUNT(*) as qtde_pets
FROM Pessoas AS a
LEFT JOIN Pets AS b
ON a.Id = b.PersonId
GROUP BY a.Id, a.Name
```